# Magento 2 Custom Theme Templates

Tags: magento2, theme, custom-theme

I've been programming Magento 1 for many years but I'm just getting into Magento 2 and I am a little confused about the theme folder structure.  From what I have found there's really no concept of theme-specific template files.  Templates are inside modules now.  To overwrite a parent theme's template, simply put your own template file in the same folder as the parent theme's file.

For example, let's say I have a theme called "Mytheme/Default" and I want to change the `footer.phtml` template for my theme.  The default one lives in `[site_root]\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\footer.phtml`.  This tells me it's in the Magento Theme extension, so I need to put my override template in `[site_root]/app/design/frontend/Mytheme/Default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml`.

However, the part that isn't clear is where I'm supposed to put template files that are entirely custom but not related to any module at all.  I have since learned that these should probably reside under the `Magento_Theme` extension, howerver, while playing around and trying things I discovered that I can create a `templates` subdirectory in my theme folder (*outside* of any Module folders) and it actually works.  I can't find anything online about this so I'm wondering if it's a side effect of how Magento looks for template files or if this is actually a supported method for creating custom templates that aren't part of an extension.

I also read that if the template file you're trying to use lives in the same Module as the XML file providing the instructions you can avoid the `Vendor_Module::` prefix on the template declaration in the XML.  For instance, if I create a new block inside the body of a page and I instantiate this using a `default.xml` file inside my theme under the `Magento_Theme` module directory, and if I put my template somewhere in the same `Magento_Theme` module directory, I should be able to use `template="path/to/template.phtml` in my layout XML instead of the longer version, `template="Magento_Theme::path/to/template.phtml"`.  This, however, does not work in my experience and I always need the `Magento_Theme::` directive.

...HOWEVER...

If I put my custom template in the (perhaps unsupported) `templates` subdirectory inside my theme's root folder (i.e. `...app/design/frontend/Mytheme/Default/templates`) I don't need any module prefix and it actually works.

Is this supported or is it just by happenstance that it's working?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow you described (putting the templates inside app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/templates) is not actually supported (actually, I've never tried myself, but if it is supported, is definetly not a good practice).

You should add your new templates inside the module folder (I ment, the folder  that overrides a module in your theme) that you actually want to add/modify this view.

For example, if you want to add a new custom template to the footer, you should add it in the following path:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/footer/my-custom-template.phtml
```

And, in your default.xml call it:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.template" template="Magento_Theme::footer/my-custom-template.phtml"/>
```

If the template is not related to any module, you should create a new module, and there you can add the template.

I hope this clarify you doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is pretty much what I thought with one exception. I assumed that templates not associated with any existing block class could live under the Magento_Theme (as long as it doesn't need a custom block class). While this may work, is it not best practice? Should I have an extension for my custom theme that holds any templates and view-related logic?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, that is kind of weird, is that you specify a random module template that doesn't exist and then you override that template in in your custom theme. You don't need to create a module. E.g. in your custom theme layout file (`/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`) you can add:

```
<referenceContainer name="top.container">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-nav-toggle" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/nav-toggle.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

And even though the module `Magento_Theme` doesn't have any such template, you can override it in your custom theme and it works, e.g. here is the contents of (`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/nav-toggle.phtml`):

```
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Toggle Nav')) ?></span></span>
```